# How to exclude part of the code with TWIG?

Tags: html, twig, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 TWIG file with this code :

```
<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 p-0 text-center">
  <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg"></i> {{ product.flag_like_product }}
</div>
```

Is it possible to exclude the following code :

```
      <div class="flag flag-like-product js-flag-like-product-14 action-flag">
        <a title="" href="/fr/flag/details/flag/like_product/14?destination=/fr/boutique/exemple-dune-boutique" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;}" rel="nofollow">
          <span class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">
            <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg"></i> J'aime
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Here is the rendering of the code :

```
<div class="row p-0 m-0">
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 p-0 text-center">
    <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg"></i>
    <div class="bs-field-like-link">
      <div class="flag flag-like-product js-flag-like-product-14 action-flag">
        <a title="" href="/fr/flag/details/flag/like_product/14?destination=/fr/boutique/exemple-dune-boutique" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;}" rel="nofollow">
          <span class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">
            <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg"></i> J'aime
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="bs-field-like-count">
      1
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 p-0 text-center">
    <i class="far fa-comment fa-lg"></i> 0
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 p-0 text-center">
    <i class="fas fa-share-alt fa-lg"></i> 0
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you reformulate the question? I'm not sure to understand what do you wanna do.
What's your template?
Why do you wanna exclude some code?
Where?

Comment: You should look for product object with method flag_like_product and edit this method. Doesn't need to be inside twig.